# Specific chord confusion: why the C# in Eb7 b9 13?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-inversions, chord-voicings

needing the expert help on the forum as I simply can't understand this. Following a vid, the player mentions he plays Eb7 9b 13 chord. The melody note is C, and he plays 1-3 (Eb, G) in left hand. What I don't understand is that in his right hand hes playing  C#,E,G,C. Does he misspoke? Or is it simply something basic I don't understand. The 9b and 13 I understand, moves the root and 7 a half step. But the C# I got no idea.

Comment: Reference to the video would reveal which actual notes (their octaves) are involved. Assuming it's piano.

Answer (score 14):

The C# is enharmonically Db, which is the b7 of the Eb7 chord. As for the 9b, it is typical to put the accidental before the chord tone, b9 instead of 9b. Also, the b9 should not be an E but rather an Fb because the letter E is used by the root. This chord can also more simply be named Eb13b9.

From low to high you have Eb, G, Db, Fb, G, C.

This is R, 3, b7, b9, 3, 13.

This particular voicing has a doubled 3rd and no 5th.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you shouldn't call it C# but rather Db... which is the *seven* in Eb7.